# How to fix NoMethodError in #show error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm trying to access a specific review through the link:

```
<%= link_to "Full Review", review_path(review) %><
```

show.html.erb:

```
 <%= @review.pro %>
```

reviews_controller.rb:

```
def show 
    @review = Review.find(params[:id])
end
```

I have a column in the review table named pro as shown in the migration file here:

```
class CreateReviews < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
  create_table :reviews do |t|
    t.string :pro
    t.string :con
    t.string :advice
    t.string :date
    t.string :role
    t.string :company

    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

end

The error I get is:

```
undefined method `pro' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= @review.pro %>
```

Even when I include 'puts @review' in the show method, nothing gets returned in the rails console.  Any advice on how to fix this?

Update when I manually include Review.find(1) in the show method:

Processing by ReviewsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Rendered reviews/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `pro' for nil:NilClass):
    1: <%= @review.pro %>
  app/views/reviews/show.html.erb:1:in`_app_views_reviews_show_html_erb___648582160945665650_70143359368840'

Comment: Likely unrelated, but your controller filename should be pluralized: `reviews_controller.rb`

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. The file name is pluralized.

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: I'm using Rails 3.2.12

Comment: You shouldn't build up URLs in links manually like that - Rails has things to do that for you, like named routes, and also the `link_to` helper. You should have something like `link_to 'Here is the full review', review_path(review)`

Comment: Drop into a Rails console and type `Review.find(1)`. Does it return your review?

Comment: Yes, it returns the review.

Comment: It's grabbing the record, but does it show the `pro` attribute? In other words, does `Review.find(1).pro` give you the pro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nil exceptions are some of the hardest to debug. You have to "follow the Nil" as @sameera207 is suggesting.

In your controller, try

```
def show 
  @review = Review.find(params[:id])
  logger.info "Review: #{@review}"
  logger.info "Review is nil? #{@review.nil?}"
end
```

If your `log/development.log` shows `Review is nil?: true` then you're not finding the right record. Your params should show in your log file, too.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be your `@review` variable is nil. (Probably you might not get a matching record in this line `Review.find(params[:id])`)

one way to avoid this error is

```
<%= @review.try(:pro) %>
```

Comment: `Review.find` will raise an exception if it doesn't find a matching record.

Comment: That's strange because when I see an item in the db with that id number.  Any reason why this could be happening though I'm able to see the review/item?

Comment: yes, I think your params[:id] might not getting the correct value, pls check that

Comment: I manually inputted Review.find(1), which I can see in my db that I'm running on localhost, and I'm still getting an error.

Comment: I mean, open u r rails console `rails c` and run `Review.find(1)` and see what u get

Comment: I'm using Solr/sunspot and have a seeds.rb file as well.  Do you think this could impact it?

Comment: can u check what u get in params[:id]

Comment: I'm seeing {"id"=>"1"} on the Rails erro page.  Is there another way you'd recommend checking what's in params[:id]?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28415/discussion-between-sameera207-and-sharataka)

Comment: I'm now in the SO chat if you would like to discuss more :D